# How do I conditionally format a WPF TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF TextBlock bound to a string.
If that string is empty, I want the TextBlock to display a warning message in another colour.

This is easy to do in code, I was wondering if there was a elegant WPF pure XAML solution for it?
I have investigated Style Triggers, but the syntax doesn't come naturally to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Adding some details to [Daniel's (slightly short) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717758/how-do-i-conditionally-format-a-wpf-textblock/2717816#2717816) as some of the needed DataTrigger stuff is not really trivial (like `{x:Null}`):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTextProperty}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyTextProperty}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Hey, the text should not be empty!"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

BTW: Did this completely from memory, *did not check it in VS or Blend*, so please excuse if there are errors in there. However, you should be able to sort them out yourself. What counts is the idea. Good luck!

Comment: In the context of the question you might want to set visibility in the style/triggers and have the text and colour set in the first line. However this answer is still good as it illustrates the beginings of more complex formatting.

Answer (score 11):

You can use Converter for this. Simply Create class with IValueConverter. After in dataBinding use this converter

For example your XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">

<Window.Resources>
    <lib:TextBlockDataConveter x:Key="DataConverter"/>
    <lib:TextBlockForegroundConverter x:Key="ColorConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=message, Converter ={StaticResource DataConverter}}" Foreground="{Binding message, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"/>
</Grid>
```

and your converters:

```
public class TextBlockDataConveter:IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return "Error Message";
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}

class TextBlockForegroundConverter:IValueConverter
{

    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {

            SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush();
            brush.Color = Colors.Red;
            return brush;
        }
        else
        {
            SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush();
            brush.Color = Colors.Black;
            return brush;

        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

it works . Check it.

Comment: Don't you feel it is a little too much code for such a simple task?!

Comment: Yes it's too much code. You can do your task with DataTriggers also. But this solution is  more flexible.

Comment: Hi Polaris, thanks, but I was looking specifically for a Xaml only solution.

Comment: “Too much code for such a simple task” is pretty much WPF in a nutshell